# What is the Best and easiest way to create a Classifer for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, classification

Sentiment analysis using Machine Learning is a hot topic. In the present situation when a person doesn't have a problem in having the training data set then which way should we create the classifier possibly the NaiveBayes classifier?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the best way but it's simple and fast:

- preprocess the input with the [Porter Stemmming algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/) (it's a process for removing the commoner morphological and inflexional endings from words in English) or similar (take a look at [Snowball](http://snowballstem.org/))
- preprocess the input flagging words before and after every negation ("never", "not", "no", "n't"):

  ```
  the movie was not great => the movie ¬was not ¬great
  ```
- Use [Bernoulli Naïve Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) (duplicate words are removed from the document and given a class, positive or negative, you assume that the words are conditionally independent of each other):
    $$P(C_j | D) = \frac{\prod_i P(x_i | C_j) P(C_j)}{P(D)}$$

  $$P(x_i | C_j) = \frac{count\ of\ x_i\ in\ documents\ of\ class\ C_j}{total\ number\ of\ words\ in\ documents\ of\ class\ C_j}$$
  ($x_i$ are the individual words of the document $D$)

  You can also use [Laplacian smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) to avoid problems if  the  classifier encounters a word that hasn't been seen in the training set:

  $$P(x_i | C_j) = \frac{1 + count\ of\ x_i\ in\ documents\ of\ class\ C_j}{2 (total\ number\ of\ words\ in\ documents\ of\ class\ C_j)}$$

This works quite well.

Further steps are *feature selection* (removing redundant features, while retaining those features that have high disambiguation capabilities) and *the use of [ngrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)* (e.g. [Fast and accurate sentiment classification using an enhanced Naive Bayes model](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6143.pdf) by Vivek Narayanan, Ishan Arora, Arjun Bhatia).